# How to plot cos x * sinh y = c using latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

-pi/2 ≤ x ≤ pi/2.

c is constant. You can just take c = 1 or anything you like

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcme to TeX SX! You can calculate solve for y in function of x first, then ask to plot it either with `pgfplots` or with `pst-plot`.

Answer (score 3):

To get you started.....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-3:3,samples=500,mark=none] {ln(1/cos(x)+sqrt(1+ (1/cos(x))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a missing `)` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code with `pstricks`. It can be compiled with `pdflatex` if if you set the compiler switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

It plots the function `y = ln((1+\sqrt(cos²x+1))/(cos x))`:

```
%%cos x sh y = 1
\documentclass[border=3pt, x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\def\f{ln((1 + sqrt(1 + (COS(x))^2))/(COS(x)))}

\begin{document}

\psset{plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12, unit=1.5}%
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.95,-0.9)(3,4)
{\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=Goldenrod1}
    \psline(-\pstPI2,-1)(-\pstPI2,6)
    \psline(\pstPI2,-1)(\pstPI2,6)}
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, xtrigLabels, arrows=->, trigLabelBase=2, dx = 1.57] (0,0)(-3,-1)(3,4)[$x$, -120][$y$, -135]
    %
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=IndianRed3}
    \psplot{-\pstPI2}{\pstPI2}{\f}%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]